# ActionScript 2.0 and swc

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a project in ActionScript 2.0.It is also having some classes that act as an interface to the native.These classes are intrinsic.
I was trying to make a set of classes as an swc.
I followed the approach mentioned in 
[How do I include a SWC in an AS2 Flash project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089072/how-do-i-include-a-swc-in-an-as2-flash-project)
But, the swf is throwing compilation error - not able to access the intrinsic classes.
Is this a limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read on this link :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001911.html it does not seem like a limitation, but there may be some rules to be followed. The Doc says:

"*The source code may contain intrinsic class definitions that contain no function bodies and are provided purely for type checking.*"

Hope this helps